# networksetup -ordernetworkservices is not working at all after Big Sur update

Tags: macos, networking

I've always used `networksetup -ordernetworkservices` from the command line with no issue.

I.e.

`networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder`

**responds with:**

> An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled. (1) ZTE
> (Hardware Port: ZTE, Device: en7) (2) Eth (Hardware Port: Ethernet,
> Device: en0)

__

`networksetup -ordernetworkservices Eth ZTE`

**responds with:**

> Wrong number of network services... No changes have been made. Note:
> Quotes must be used around service names which contain spaces (ie.
> "Built-in Ethernet").
> ** Error: The parameters were not valid.

__

And now the above error is happening. No matter what combinations or solutions I try nothing works. This only started to occur after I updated to Big Sur. My command is valid.

Any advice on how I can get this command working again? It's very important to my business.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use quotes around the servicenames.
networksetup -ordernetworkservices "Eth" "ZTE"